# TcpChannel could not be found

Tags: c#, remoting

I'm following a lab tutorial on .NET remoting and for that I need to create TcpChannel object. For that I have added using System.Runtime.Remoting namespace but it still gives me an error **The type or namespace name 'TcpChannel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. I can't figure out what is causing this problem. I even googled it. Here's my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.Remoting;

namespace RemotingServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpChannel channel = new TcpChannel(8001);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *[TcpChannel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.channels.tcp.tcpchannel%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)* class is located in *System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp*, so you have to get `using` that. Also check if you reference *System.Runtime.Remoting.dll* in your project.